# C program to print prime no.s till n

Tags: c, nested-loops

Below is the code I have written for asking the user to input a number n and printing the prime numbers till n. 
The output I am getting is only till 3. The program isn't going into the loop beyond 3 and displaying output as :1 2 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
        int a, i, j, flag = 0;
        printf("Enter n?\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("Prime no.s till %d are: ",a);
        for(i=1; i<=a; i++)
        {
                for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
                {
                        if(i%j==0)
                        {
                                flag=1;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                if(flag==0)
                        printf("%d ",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You never reset `flag` to `0`.

Comment: You're breaking out of the loop at whenever you reach an even number, so you're never making it past 4.

Comment: @user3814613: Only the *inner* loop is being broken out of.

Comment: Do you see the futility of checking i= 4, 6, 8 (even numbers)?   you can make your loop 2x faster by only checking the odd numbers: `i +=2`

Comment: regarding this line: `void main()`   Per the C standard, there are only a couple of valid signatures for the function: `main()`.   They are: `int main( void )`  and `int main( int, char ** )`   Notice that both have a return type of `int`, not `void`.   Your compiler should have told you about this problem.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: variable names should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both).  follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  For ease of readability (programs are read many times)  separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for readability, never use tabs for indenting (each word processor, editor has the tab stops/tab width set individually.   Strongly suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that allows several indent levels across the page AND is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `flag` to tell if a candidate is prime or not.  But because you initialize it at the start of the program, as soon as you find a non-prime, every subsequent candidate will also be considered non-prime.

You need to re-initialize `flag` each time you change `i`.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes I see, firstly `1` is not prime, so start the loop at `2`.

Secondly, you must initialise `flag` inside the first loop

```
for(i=2; i<=a; i++)
    {
    flag=0;
    for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
    //...
```

Program session:

```
Enter n?
19
Prime no.s till 19 are: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    
        int a,j,i, flag=0;
        printf("Enter n?\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("Prime no.s till %d are:",a);
        
        for(i=2;i<=a;i++)
        {
            flag=0;
                for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
                {
                        if(i%j==0)
                        break;
                    
                }
                if(flag==0)
                        printf("%d\n",i);           
        }
    
    return 0;
}
```